# Mechanism of overridding methods in a Ruby class

Tags: ruby

Suppose I want to override a method of an existing class `Array` as below.

```
class Array
  def to_s
    self.join(',')
  end
end
```

So my question is - How does this overriding work? Does this add this definition of method to_s to the class `Array`? I mean if the class contained 'n' method definitions, it would now contain 'n+1' method definitions. Also, is it that there are two definitions of `to_s` method and the one that is added last is the one that would work?

Thanks.

Comment: The new method overrides the old one, so the number of methods in the object does not change. And the last one works.

Comment: Your answers are a google search away from you.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't overriding the method, you are re-defining it.  The one that was there is gone, replaced with what you put in.  This is a risky thing to do w/the standard libraries, you don't know what behavior other code is relying upon.

You can try it w/your own class.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts 'One'
  end
end

class Foo
  def bar
    puts 'Two'
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
# Two

class Foo
  def bar
    puts 'Three'
    super
  end
end

Foo.new.bar
# Three
# test.rb:18:in `bar': super: no superclass method `bar' 
#   for #<Foo:0x007fd642029278> (NoMethodError)
```